# Recursive Dynamic Angular Form based on ng-template, binding missing with Component

Tags: angular, ng-template, angular-dynamic-components, recursive-component

I was creating this project (*Source Project*) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkshmk; I had error but I 'solve' (with problems) here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70794789/811293
The problems are: `Validation`s aren't working at Select level 2 or more.

I was checking this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56191376/811293 for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56176052/811293).

Then I was trying to change my solution to based on `ng-template`, `ng-container` and `ngTemplateOutlet`

The transition is in this project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gns1kn

In the ***json-form.component.html*** file ([source project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkshmk)) I changed

```
    <selects
      *ngIf="control.type === 'select'"
      [control]="control"
      [visible]="true"
      (addControl)="onAddControl($event)"
      [formBuilder]="myFormBuilder"
    ></selects>
```

To ([destiny project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gns1kn)) in the same ***json-form.component.html*** file

```
      <ng-container
        *ngIf="control.type === 'select'"
        [ngTemplateOutlet]="selects"
        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
          incomingControl: control,
          incomingVisible: true
        }"
      >
```

I removed the `SelectsComponent` (***selects.component.ts*** and ***selects.component.html***) and I changed to `ng-template`

```
<ng-template
  #selects
  let-control="incomingControl"
  let-visible="incomingVisible"
>
...
</ng-template>
```

The recursion in the ***selects.component.html*** file ([source project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkshmk)) for `selects` was

```
  <selects
    *ngIf="child.type === 'select'"
    [control]="child"
    [parentControl]="control"
    [formBuilder]="formBuilder"
  ></selects>
```

was moved to ([destiny project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gns1kn)) in the same ***json-form.component.html*** file

```
      <ng-container
        *ngIf="child.type === 'select'"
        [ngTemplateOutlet]="selects"
        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
          incomingControl: child,
          parentControl: control
        }"
      >
      </ng-container>
```

**NOTE:**

Due to the [source project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkshmk) has a longer `json` with a deeper nested(recursion) , I changed to a shorter `json` in the [destiny project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gns1kn).
This change can be done in the [home.page.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gns1kn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.page.ts) file, changing the needed line from `.get('/assets/company.json')` to `.get('/assets/nested-select.json')`.

I would like to show the nested selects when the click is performed as the [source project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wkshmk)

[image]

**THE PROBLEM:**

[image]

As you can see in the above image; (at left side in the `json` file) the first component with the name `company` has children!
In the display view yo can see: `"control.children: ...."`

That is shown due to **lines** `100` and `101` in the ***json-form.component.html*** file.

```
      control.children:<br />
      {{ control.children | json }}<br />
```

But, When the `click` event is performed, the chilren are missing in the component side!!! As you can check in the image.

In  the component at from line `83` through line `85`
***json-form.component.ts*** the file

```
console.log(
  this.control?.children.length > 0 ? 'with children' : 'without children'
);
```

**QUESTIONS:**

**What is the reason to lost the binding between the Component and Template?**

**How solve the problem with initial `control` (`company`)?**

Answer (score 0):

> What is the reason to lost the binding between the Component and Template?

In the JsonFormComponent, you have declared `control` as an @Input binding which is `undefined` as you do not have any `control` input binding below:

```html
<app-json-form [jsonFormData]="formData" [visible]="true"></app-json-form>
```

`control.children | json` here control refers to one of the controls within jsonFormData, as you are looping through it's controls via `*ngFor` directive. Whereas within the component onSelectChange() method, you are referring to `this.control` which is undefined as explained earlier.

It worked in your source project, since you did pass `control` via input property binding to the SelectsComponent and used the same within it's template too.

```html
<selects
  *ngIf="control.type === 'select'"
  [control]="control"
  [visible]="true"
  (addControl)="onAddControl($event)"
  [formBuilder]="myFormBuilder"
></selects>
```

> How solve the problem with initial control (company)?

To get hold of the control within `onSelectChange` method, you can pass the control reference from the template and use the same in the method instead of `this.control`.

```html
(selectionChange)="onSelectChange(control, $event.value)"
```

[image]

---

**Edit:** For displaying subsequent fields, made below changes in json-form.component.html

- Removed `<br>` element from line 8 (Not mandatory, but the screenshot shown has this change)
- Modified line 38 to pass correct context object properties to `ng-template`

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, but Unfortunately; When I made a click, the next `Select` is  not shown still. (In the *destiny* project I changed the `json` file as *source* project to `.get('/assets/company.json')`). I said thanks again!

Comment: @joseluisbz You would need to modify the logic as within `ng-template`  the `*ngIf="control?.children"` and `*ngIf="control.type === 'select' && visible"` would be failing for subsequent select.

Comment: Hmmm, but the `control` only needs to be shown when the click is performed. One Level per click! As the `Source Project`...

Comment: @joseluisbz I have edited answer to display subsequent field(s). See if it helps